# Exactness of a sequence

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Denote $X$ a rational projective surface, $\left|-K_X\right| $ not empty and $F_0 \in \left|-K_X\right|$   . In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.0930.pdf) ((2) on page 7) the authors state the sequence
\begin{align*}
0 \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_X \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_X(n F_0) \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{F_0}(n F_0) \longrightarrow 0
\end{align*}
is exact. This is not quite an exact sequence which arises from the sequence associated to ideal sheaves, and I fail to see that it is in fact exact.

Comment: Either the kernel should be $O_X((n-1)F_0)$ or the cokernel should be $O_{nF_0}(nF_0)$   to make the sequence exact.